# How do I get the list from my result in python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have written the following code in python 3.8;

```
    import galois
    GF = galois.GF(2)
    f = galois.Poly([1,0,0,1], field=GF)
    g = galois.Poly([1,1,0], field=GF)
    c=f * g
    d=c.coeffs
```

The output I am getting is

```
d=GF([1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0], order=2)
```

Now, I only want the list as my answer, i.e,

```
d=[1,1,0,1,1,0]
```

Can anybody help me with how to separate the list from my output d ?

I have tried the following code to get the list

```
v=list(str(d))
u=[ int(x) for s in v for x in s.split(',')]
```

But this is giving me the following error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

Comment: Can you run the following and show the output? `print(d)` and `print(type(d))`.

Answer (score 1):

This output is a numpy array so simply convert it into a list

```
d.tolist()
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```